# Scrapy - POST request is called on referred url not initial one

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am submitting a `FormRequest`to change the page number of multiple pages of results.

When I use the scrapy shell, the `Post` request goes through:

```
> `2017-05-21 22:44:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
> 2017-05-21 22:44:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/robots.txt> (referer:
> None) 2017-05-21 22:44:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200)
> <POST http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php>
> (referer: None) True 2017-05-21 22:44:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
> Crawled (200) <POST
> http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php>
> (referer: None) True 2017-05-21 22:44:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
> Crawled (200) <POST
> http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php>
> (referer: None) True 2017-05-21 22:44:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
> Crawled (200) <POST
> http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php>
> (referer: None) True 2017-05-21 22:44:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
> Crawled (200) <POST
> http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php>
> (referer: None) True`
```

Using this request sequence:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import FormRequest
>>> url = 'http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php'
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     payload={'pageNum': str(i)}
...     r = FormRequest(url, formdata=payload)
...     fetch(r)
...     view(response)
```

But when I implement the `post`request into my scrapy code the `post` is referred back to the initial search site.

```
`2017-05-21 22:58:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-05-21 22:58:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php> (referer: None)
2017-05-21 22:58:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/**search.php>** (referer: http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php)`
```

Of course the `search.php` doesn't have the data I'm looking for. Why is this `Post` in my code refering it back to search and not in the shell? And how can I stop the referral while still going to the next set of results?
Scrapy code:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class Foo(Spider):
    name = "schoolsTest"
    allowed_domains = ["australianschoolsdirectory.com.au"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'pageNum': str(5), 'search': 'true'}, callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `from_response` (since you not dealing with form) and you can use a scrapy `start_requests` method:

```
import scrapy

class Foo(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "schoolsTest"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php"
        # Change 5 to 488 to parse all search result
        for i in range(1, 5):
            payload = {'pageNum': str(i)}
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=payload)

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract all links from search page and make absolute urls
        links = response.xpath('//div[@class="listing-header"]/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            full_url = response.urljoin(link)
            # Make a Request to each detail page
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: the world needs more people like you vold, got it now, seriously thanks so so much! :)

Comment: I'll be back to +1 this when I've got the rep

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad I can help. I slightly edited my answer and add few line to show how you can extract links to a detail page.